# Remote Desktop Connection - Stuck running @ 30 Hz?

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, amd-radeon

I use a freesync monitor and when I run RDC to either my laptop or a hyper-v session I've noticed that freesync kicks in (borderless windowed mode) and will go between 30->60(doubled from LFC?)->75(my display refresh rate) and all over the place. I end up having to disable Freesync which is not ideal.

Is there something causing RDC to only refresh @ 30hz? The connection also feels very laggy even though it's either on my PC (Hyper-V) or right next to me (Laptop).

Is there a way to force RDC to at least run 60hz if not the full 75hz my monitor supports? I've tried both windows 10 anniversary and now also the latest creators update. Also I'm not sure if it's freesync causing the issue or not, because it does seem to lag even when disabled, just not as much. There is still a noticeable delay when typing (programming) sometimes which is an issue. Having freesync enabled just really highlights the issue because I can see the hz on the monitor's overlay swap between 30-60 constantly.

`Monitor: ACER XR341CK`
`GPU: AMD Fury`
`Windows: 10`

Comment: I think the proper solution would be to disable FreeSync for RDC, if that is at all possible. Maybe in your graphics driver’s application-specific settings?

Comment: @DanielB afaik there is no option to do so. I wouldn't mind just disabling it for all borderless windowed windows at this point if that was an option, but I haven't seen one.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround, "[Frame rate is limited to 30 FPS in Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 remote sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/remote/frame-rate-limited-to-30-fps)" on Microsoft Learn, shows which registry keys to manipulate using an example resulting in 60 Hz:

> Create a `DWMFRAMEINTERVAL` entry in registry subkey
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations` to change the maximum frame rate limit on the
> remote session host. To do this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Start ***Registry Editor***.
> 2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
>    `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer\WinStations`
> 3. On the *Edit* menu, click *New*, and then click `DWORD`(32-bit) Value.
> 4. Type `DWMFRAMEINTERVAL`, and then press **Enter**.
> 5. Right-click `DWMFRAMEINTERVAL`, click **Modify**.
> 6. Type `f` (or click *Decimal* and type `15`) in the *Value* data box, and then click **OK**. This
>    sets the maximum frame rate to 60 frames per second (FPS).

You shouldn't need to restart the target, just reconnect the client.

It gave me 67 Hz, and different values will give different rates, but I'm not sure what the relationship is. If a value doesn't work, you'll just see a black screen and so will need another way to delete or change the key, such as PowerShell remoting.